# Java UDP Client/Server Datagram Issue - NAT - OSX 10.9

Tags: java, sockets, udp, nat, datagram

I have recently started to create a 2D side scroller game, using only Mac OSX Mavericks' java 7 libraries, when I got to multiplayer, I was able to create client and server handlers for my game and they work just fine when the client sends data to 'localhost' but when I use my external IP the server never receives the data, I believe it is a problem with the client considering that it works when the client is told to send to 'localhost' but not my external IP, I have port forwarded the port and local IP of the server and my Mac's firewall is disabled. Is there a problem with UDP datagram sockets in java 7 or on macs?

ClientHandler.java

```
package com.diedericksclan.main.network;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.diedericksclan.main.gui.*;
import com.diedericksclan.main.network.handling.Packet;
import com.diedericksclan.main.network.handling.PacketDisconnect;
import com.diedericksclan.main.network.handling.PacketLogin;
import com.diedericksclan.main.network.handling.PacketMovement;
import com.diedericksclan.main.network.handling.PlayerMP;
import com.diedericksclan.main.network.handling.Packet.PacketType;

public class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    private InetAddress IPaddress;
    private DatagramSocket dataSocket;
    private DisplayHandler game;
    public static boolean connected = false;
    private int serverPort = 2048;
    private int port;

    public ClientHandler(DisplayHandler game, String ipaddress, int serverPort) {
        this.game = game;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
        try {
            this.dataSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            this.IPaddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipaddress);
            this.port = dataSocket.getPort();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     public void callHost()
     { 
          this.sendByteData("-3".getBytes());
     } 

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            byte[] gameData = new byte[8192];
            DatagramPacket in = new DatagramPacket(gameData, gameData.length);
            try {
                this.dataSocket.receive(in);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.parsePacket(in.getData(), in.getAddress(), in.getPort());
        }
    }

    private void parsePacket(byte[] data, InetAddress address, int port) {
        String dataString = new String(data).trim();
        System.out.println("Server[" + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port + "] Data Recived: " + dataString);
        PacketType type = Packet.lookupPacket(dataString.substring(0, 2));
        Packet packet = null;
        switch (type) {
        default:
            break;
        case CONNECT:
            this.connected = true;
            break;
        case SHUTDOWN:
            this.game.setCurrentDisplay(this.game.dispMMenu);
            this.game.dispGame.getEntities().clear();
            this.connected = false;
            break;
        case INVALID:
            break;
        case LOGIN:
            packet = new PacketLogin(data);
            System.out.println("[" + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + Integer.toString(port) + "] " + ((PacketLogin)packet).getUsername() + " - Has just logged onto the server!");
            PlayerMP playerLogin = new PlayerMP(game, ((PacketLogin)packet).getUsername(), address, port);
            this.game.dispGame.getEntities().add(playerLogin);
            break;
        case DISCONNECT:
            packet = new PacketDisconnect(data);
            System.out.println("[" + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + Integer.toString(port) + "] " + ((PacketDisconnect)packet).getUsername() + " - Has just disconnected from the server!");
            int index = this.game.dispGame.getEntityIndex(((PacketDisconnect)packet).getUsername());
            this.game.dispGame.removePlayer(((PacketDisconnect)packet).getUsername());
            if(this.game.dispGame.getEntities().get(index).getUsername() == ((PacketDisconnect)packet).getUsername()) {
                this.game.dispGame.removePlayer(((PacketDisconnect)packet).getUsername());
            }
            this.connected = false;
            break;
        case MOVEMENT:
            packet = new PacketMovement(data);
            for(PlayerMP p : this.game.dispGame.getEntities()) {
                if(p.getUsername().equals(((PacketMovement)packet).getUsername())) {
                    p.setX(((PacketMovement)packet).getX());
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public void sendByteData(byte[] data) {
        DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, this.IPaddress, this.serverPort);
        try {
            this.dataSocket.send(out);
            System.out.println("Sending byte[] data to ServerHandler(" + out.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + out.getPort() + ")   From: " + InetAddress.getByName("localhost").getHostAddress() + ":" + this.dataSocket.getLocalPort());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ServerHandler.java

```
package com.diedericksclan.main.network;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.diedericksclan.main.gui.*;
import com.diedericksclan.main.network.handling.*;
import com.diedericksclan.main.network.handling.Packet.*;
import com.diedericksclan.main.network.handling.*;
import com.diedericksclan.main.recource.*;

public class ServerHandler extends Thread {

    private DatagramSocket dataSocket;
    private DisplayHandler game;
    public List<PlayerMP> players = new ArrayList<PlayerMP>();

    public ServerHandler(DisplayHandler game, int port) {
        this.game = game;
        try {
            this.dataSocket = new DatagramSocket(port, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2"));
            System.out.println(this.dataSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + port + "    ===    " + this.dataSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + port);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("made");
        while (true) {
            byte[] data = new byte[8192];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            try {
                dataSocket.receive(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.parsePacket(packet.getData(), packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
        }
    }

    private void parsePacket(byte[] data, InetAddress address, int port) {
        String dataString = new String(data).trim();
        PacketType type = Packet.lookupPacket(dataString.substring(0, 2));
        Packet packet = null;
        switch (type) {
        default:
            break;
        case CONNECT:
            System.out.println("Here");
            this.sendByteData("-3".getBytes(), address, port);
            break;
        case INVALID:
            break;
        case LOGIN:
            packet = new PacketLogin(data);
            System.out.println("[" + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port + "] " + ((PacketLogin)packet).getUsername() + " - Has just joined the server!");
            PlayerMP playerLogin = new PlayerMP(game, ((PacketLogin)packet).getUsername(), address, port);
            this.addConnection(playerLogin, (PacketLogin)packet);
            break;
        case DISCONNECT:
            packet = new PacketDisconnect(data);
            System.out.println("[" + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port + "] " + ((PacketDisconnect)packet).getUsername() + " - Has just left the server!");
            this.removeConnection((PacketDisconnect)packet);
            break;
        case MOVEMENT:
            System.out.println("Here");
            packet = new PacketMovement(data);
            this.players.get(this.getPlayerIndex(((PacketMovement)packet).getUsername())).setX(((PacketMovement)packet).getX());
            this.sendByteDataToAll(packet.getData(), address, port);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void addConnection(PlayerMP player, PacketLogin login) {
        boolean alreadyOn = false;
        for(PlayerMP p : players) {
            if(player.getUsername().equals(p.getUsername())) {
                if(p.IPaddress == null) {
                    p.IPaddress = player.IPaddress;
                }
                if(p.port == -1) {
                    p.port = player.port;
                }
                alreadyOn = true;
            } else if(!player.getUsername().equals(p.getUsername())) {
                this.sendByteDataToAll(login.getData(), player.IPaddress, player.port);
                login = new PacketLogin(p.getUsername());
                this.sendByteData(login.getData(), player.IPaddress, player.port);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error whilst trying to send data to clients");
                this.sendByteData(login.getData(), p.IPaddress, p.port);
            }
        }
        if(!alreadyOn) {
            this.players.add(player);
        }
    }

    public void removeConnection(PacketDisconnect packet) {
        this.players.remove(this.getPlayerIndex(packet.getUsername()));
        packet.writeData(this);
    }

    public PlayerMP getPlayer(String username) {
        for(PlayerMP p : players) {
            if (p.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getPlayerIndex(String username) {
        int index = 0;
        for(PlayerMP p : players) {
            if (p.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return index;
    }

    public void sendByteData(byte[] data, InetAddress IPaddress, int port) {
        if(port != -1) {
            DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPaddress, port);
            try {
                this.dataSocket.send(out);
                System.out.println("Sending byte[] data to ClientHandler(" + out.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + out.getPort() + ")");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendByteDataToAll(byte[] data) {
        for(PlayerMP p : players) {
            sendByteData(data, p.IPaddress, p.port);
        }
    }

    public void sendByteDataToAll(byte[] data, InetAddress IPaddress, int port) {
        for(PlayerMP p : players) {
            if(p.IPaddress != IPaddress) {
                sendByteData(data, p.IPaddress, p.port);
            } else if(p.port != port) {
                sendByteData(data, p.IPaddress, p.port);
            } else {

            }
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        this.sendByteDataToAll("-2".getBytes()); //Disconnects all players when server is closed
        this.players.clear();
    }
}
```

DisplayHandler.java (Where the client & server handlers are created)

```
@Override
    public void start() {
        this.shread.start();
        this.soundThread.start();
        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Do you want to host a lan server?") == 0) {
            this.server = new ServerHandler(this, 2048); //Creates server if user wants to. Prams: DisplayHandler, int port - the port the server should host on
            this.server.start();
            System.out.println("Done1");
        }
        this.client = new ClientHandler(this, "MYEXTERNALIP", 2048); //Creates Client. Prams: DisplayHandler, String IP - The servers IP, int port - Servers port
        this.client.start();
        this.setCurrentDisplay(dispMMenu);
        this.onOpen();
        this.client.callHost();
        System.out.println("Done");
        //this.sound.addMidi("finalcountdown", "test.mid");
        //this.sound.playMid("finalcountdown", true);
    }
```

Comment: can you be more specific about that external server address you're talking about? have you tried to ping your external server address? Please tell me if you're able to reach it with ping

Comment: The external address i am using is just my wan ip, you can find it at ipchicken.com , And no I haven't pinged it, i'll see what it is then try to do so. thanks.

Comment: open a command shell, (cmd.exe) and type type 'ping www.google.com', then you see the results; try to ping your server by simply typing 'ping 192.168.0.1'  (i don't know your servers ip)

Comment: Thanks, this is what my terminal outputs: **bold**64 bytes from MYEXTERNALIP: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.517 ms**bold** Is there a way to check a port?

Comment: ok, you can ping it, that means can exclude the problem, that the server is unreachable! thats good so far! check your firewall settings if port and protocol are allow! Java socket works good, so the problem is not in java... it's somewhere between those two sockets!

Comment: When I go into System Preferences >> Security & Privacy >> Firewall It gives me the option to turn on my firewall and it says my firewall is off.

Comment: do you use a router between your client/server? if it's inside of the routers subnet it should be working, if it goes 'outside' you must check the firewall settings from the router, too...

Comment: The client and server are on the same router for testing purposes, but they both go out into the 'internet' to give each other information, they don't use pan, only nat. And I doubt my router is the problem as it I host a mine craft server without any errors, but how would I check if it is my router?

Comment: check your router configuration, usually you can check them with an browser; type your routers ip into the adress field, then you should be able to see the settings (mostly it's 10.0.0.1 or 192.168.0.1)

Comment: It is enabled but I can't disable it, there is no option for that. I'll do more research, brb.

Comment: The only option it is giving me is to enable full cone nat, which i did but it still won't work. Also, as I plan to publish it would the client have to do this if they want to join a server? I know they'll have to do this if they want to host one.